# Dual of a simple constrained least-squares problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

For the purpose of drawing, the example cvx code for the [regularized least-squares](http://cvxopt.org/examples/book/rls.html)  solves the following problem

> \begin{align}\text{minimize}\quad &\left\|Ax - b \right\|_2^2;\\ \text{subject to}\;        &x{'}x = \alpha\end{align}

It is claimed that the following is a dual

> \begin{align}\text{maximize}\quad &-t-u\alpha;\\\text{subject to}\;&\begin{bmatrix}uI & 0 \\ 0 & t\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}A & b\end{bmatrix}'\begin{bmatrix}A & b\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0         \end{align}

I don't see how this is the case

---

The Lagrange function is

$L(u,x)  = \begin{pmatrix}
     x \\  
     -1  
 \end{pmatrix}^T \left(\begin{pmatrix}
     uI_n & 0\\  
     0 & 0 
 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
     A^T\\  
     b^T 
 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
     A & b 
 \end{pmatrix}\right) \begin{pmatrix}
     x\\  
     -1 
 \end{pmatrix}-u\alpha$

and one can introduce a slack variable $t$, but how does semi definite positivity pops out in the dual ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lagrange function that you wrote is slightly incorrect. You have to exchange $b^T$ and $b$. To obtain the dual that you are looking for:

\begin{align}
\max_{u\in \mathbb R}\min_{x\in \mathbb R^n} \left\|Ax-b\right\|^2 + u\left(\alpha - \left\|x\right\|^2\right)&=\max_{u\in \mathbb R} \left(\alpha u + \min_{x\in \mathbb R^n} \left\|Ax-b\right\|^2 - u\left\|x\right\|^2\right)\\
\end{align}

Where the last one is obtained by changing the variables $u$, $t$ by $-u$, $-t$.

Since

Now \begin{align}
\min_{x\in \mathbb R^n} \left\|Ax-b\right\|^2 - u\left\|x\right\|^2 &= \max_{t\in \mathbb R}\, t; \; \forall x\in\mathbb R^n, \left\|Ax-b\right\|^2 - u\left\|x\right\|^2 \ge t\\
&= \max_{t\in \mathbb R}\, t; \; \forall x\in\mathbb R^n, \left\|Ax-b\right\|^2 - u\left\|x\right\|^2 - t \ge 0\\
&= \max_{t\in \mathbb R}\, t; \; \forall x\in\mathbb R^n, \begin{bmatrix}x\\ -1\end{bmatrix}^T\left(\begin{bmatrix}\\ A 
 & b\\ &\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}\\ A & b\\ &\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}uI & 0\\ 0 & t\end{bmatrix}\right)\begin{bmatrix}x\\ -1\end{bmatrix} \ge 0\\
&= \max_{t\in \mathbb R} t;\; \forall x\in\mathbb R^n,\; \forall y\in\mathbb R,\;\begin{bmatrix}-yx\\ y\end{bmatrix}^T\left(\begin{bmatrix}\\ A 
 & b\\ &\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}\\ A & b\\ &\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}uI & 0\\ 0 & t\end{bmatrix}\right)\begin{bmatrix}-yx\\ y\end{bmatrix} \ge 0\\
&= \max_{t\in \mathbb R} t;\; \forall z\in \mathbb R^{n+1},\; z^T\left(\begin{bmatrix}\\ A 
 & b\\ &\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}\\ A & b\\ &\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}uI & 0\\ 0 & t\end{bmatrix}\right)z \ge 0\\
&= \max_{t\in \mathbb R} t;\; \begin{bmatrix}\\ A 
 & b\\ &\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}\\ A & b\\ &\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}uI & 0\\ 0 & t\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
\end{align}

So

\begin{align}
\max_{u\in \mathbb R}\min_{x\in \mathbb R^n} \left\|Ax-b\right\|^2 + u\left(\alpha - \left\|x\right\|^2\right)&=\max_{u\in \mathbb R,\, t\in \mathbb R} \alpha u + t;\; \begin{bmatrix}\\ A 
 & b\\ &\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}\\ A & b\\ &\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}uI & 0\\ 0 & t\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0\\
&=\max_{u\in \mathbb R,\, t\in \mathbb R} -\alpha u - t;\; \begin{bmatrix}\\ A 
 & b\\ &\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}\\ A & b\\ &\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}uI & 0\\ 0 & t\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0\\
\end{align}

Comment: (of course, sorry for the mistake)

Comment: @nicolas Is it clear now how to obtain the correct dual?

Comment: I guess, I was missing that z step. checking

Comment: looks ok to me. going from $(x,1)$ with $x\in R^n $ to $z\in R^{n+1}$ is clean

Comment: Great, that'S the idea.